# Tapestry 5 custom component in form - access during validation

Tags: forms, dependency-injection, custom-component, tapestry

A have problem with accessing my custom components (which are used as parts of the form).

Here is the story:
I have dynamic form which have few modes of work. Each mode can be selected and loaded into form body with AJAX. It looks like that (template):

```
<t:form t:id = "form">
    <p class= "calcModeTitle">
        ${message:modeLabel}: <select t:id="modeSelect"
                  t:type="select" 
                  t:model="modesModel" 
                  t:value="selectedMode"  
                  t:blankOption="NEVER" 
                  t:encoder="modeEncoder"
                  t:zone = "modeZone"
        />
    </p>

    <div class="horizontal_tab">
        <t:errors/>
    </div>

    <t:zone t:id="modeZone" id="modeZone" t:update="show">
        <t:if test="showCompany">
            <t:delegate to="block:companyBlock" />
        </t:if>
        <t:if test="showPersonal">
            <t:delegate to="block:personalBlock" />
        </t:if>
        <t:if test="showMulti">
            <t:delegate to="block:multiBlock" />
        </t:if>
    </t:zone>

    <t:block id="companyBlock">
         <t:modes.CompanyMode t:id="company"/>
    </t:block>

    <t:block id="personalBlock">
        <t:modes.PersonalMode t:id="personal" />
    </t:block>

    <t:block id="multiBlock">
        <t:modes.MultiMode t:id="multi" />
    </t:block>

    <div class="horizontal_tab">
        <input type="submit" value="${message:submit_label}" class="submitButton thickBtn"/>
    </div>

</t:form>
```

AJAX works pretty well and form changes accordingly the "modeSelect" state. But i run into problem when submitting the form. I have in class definition hooks for components placed as:

```
//----form elements
@Component(id = "form")
private Form form;

@InjectComponent
private CompanyMode company;

@InjectComponent
private PersonalMode personal;

@InjectComponent
private MultiMode multi;
```

where *Mode classes are my own components, containing form elements and input components. I planned to get access to them during validation, and check values supplied by user with form, but when I am trying to reach anything from them I've got nullPointerException - it seems that component are not initialized in my class definition of form. On the other hand form component is injected properly (I am able to write some error for example). I am a bit lost now. How to properly inject my components to class page containing the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic forms in tapestry are a bit complicated. Tapestry passes a [t:formdata](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.html#FORM_DATA) request parameter which contains the serialized form entities. This is then used serverside in the POST to re-hydrate initial form state. This must be kept up-to-date with what the client sees.

If you want to add dynamic content to a form via ajax, you will need to use the [FormInjector](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormInjector.html). You might want to take a look at the source code for the [AjaxFormLoop](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/AjaxFormLoop.html) to see an example.

If you want to render hidden form fragments and make them visible based on clientside logic, you can use the [FormFragment](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormFragment.html)

Comment: Thanks for hint, FormFragment with some server-side conditions done its work. It seems that reloading the form by AJAX is OK as long as I am not messing with its structure. Fortunately I don't need to inject anything into form, I can put everything at once and control visibility by mentioned FormFragment. Thanks again, you've saved my day (or even a couple of them ;) )

Comment: Yes, reloading the entire form is fine because you will get a new ```t:formdata``` value along with the new form. Try viewing the HTML source and you will see it.

Comment: Well, I even succeed in AJAX reloading only a part of it, but still i kept the structure the same. Anyway I got what I needed and more or less understand why it works now and why didn't earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are doing, this may be dangerous. ```t:formdata``` is tapestry's way of knowing what entities were used to render the form. If you don't keep this up-to-date... tapestry may, for example, update the wrong entity.

Answer (score 0):

From tapestry guide:

> A block does not normally render; any component or contents you put
>   inside a block will not ordinarily be rendered. However, by injecting
>   the block you have precise control over when and if the content
>   renders.

Try to use here either "t:if" or "t:delegate".

Something like this:

```
<t:zone t:id="modeZone" id="modeZone" t:update="show">
      <t:delegate to="myBlock" /> 
</t:zone>

<t:block t:id="companyBlock">
     <t:modes.CompanyMode t:id="company"/>
</t:block>
<t:block t:id="personalBlock">
    <t:modes.PersonalMode t:id="personal" />
</t:block>

<t:block t:id="multiBlock">
    <t:modes.MultiMode t:id="multi" />
</t:block>
```

java:

```
@Inject
private Block companyBlock, personalBlock, multiBlock;

public Block getMyBlock(){
    if (getShowCompany()) return companyBlock;
    if (getShowPersonal()) return personalBlock;
    return multiBlock;
}
```

Comment: Technically it's just another way to do what I had in code. The problem was that I was changing content of the form with AJAX, which seemed to be not allowed in Tapestry (at least not just by switching block).